# Casting problems with ArrayList

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to write this correctly so it will not generate compiler errors:

```
class AnElement implements IElement { ... }

protected ArrayList<AnElement> someElements() {
    ...
}

protected ArrayList<IElement> elements() {
    return (ArrayList<IElement>) someElements(); // this doesn't work...
    // return someElements();                    // ... neither does this
}
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: hmm.. just realized the word Element is not the best for this example, it's just I had that as part of my actual class I use in my real code

Comment: Define _doesn't work_. What compiler errors? What do you think they mean?

Comment: "Incompatible Types" error in the IDE. IDE has a big red line under the code. Required: ArrayList<IElement>, Found: ArrayList<AnElement>

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: You're right, that one's a better dupe-target. I'll reopen this, and you can reclose as a dupe of that?

Comment: Just for the future though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are invariant so you could do

```
protected List<? extends IElement> elements() {
    return someElements(); 
}
```

Comment: Or even better, code to the interface and do `protected List<IElement> someElements()` instead.

Comment: @MickMnemonic that probably wouldnt compile as compiler cant be sure what exact implementation of `IElement` is returned from `someElements`.....:)

Comment: It does compile with the original code.

Comment: In general, you should avoid returning wildcard types and instead _return the most specific type_. The amazing Angelika Langer [explains why](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ303). (Might not make that much of a difference when `IElement` is an `interface`, but still.)

Comment: actually yes the base is an interface IElement.. but then there is AnElement implements IElement and ChildOfAnElement extends AnElement... _and more_. I simplified things in the original post. Basically all objects are guaranteed to be of IElement ...